# What does “ Now, the question is how much to do in the PCs” mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

in an extract from D5 Conference by Wall street journal I read:

> I think there's going to be tremendous revolution, you know,
> in the experiences of the post-PC devices. **Now, the question
> is how much to do in the PCs.** And I think I'm sure Microsoft is ㅡ
> we're working on some really cool stuff, but some of it has to be tempered
> a little bit. Because you do have, you know, these tens of millions, in our
> case, or hundreds of millions in Bill's case, users that are familiar with
> something that.
> (the rest omitted)

I don't understand this part in bold. Please explain this sentence's meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that what the author means with "in the PCs" can be (roughly) replaced with "during what remains of the PC era," i.e., they're looking forward to a revolution in post-PC devices, but during the current period and for some time from now, PCs will still be an important part of the tech sphere, and there is still significant room for improvement and innovation in PC technology, before the revolution hits and things shift toward a more post-PC-centric environment.

Comment: thanks for your answering, but there's something I don't understand -> during what remains of the PC era -> please make it easy

Comment: So what the author appears to be saying is this: at some time in the future, a revolution is going to occur with respect to the experiences people will have using post-PC devices (what that means may come from context). When that time comes, the PC will be effectively obsolete. *But between now and that point,* there is still major work to be done in the field of PCs. And they're saying Microsoft is working hard on innovations in the PC market, but that Microsoft's development has to be tempered with the expectation that the future is going to move beyond the familiar PC to something ... new.

Comment: you mean that "in the PCs" means "in the field of PCs"??

Comment: Correct. I think the quoted person is also subtly implying there is a limited amount of time. So, when the quoted person says "Now, the question is how much to do in the PCs," what they really mean is "In the future, we're going to move beyond PCs. Now, the question is how much do we want to do *now* in the field of PCs, before we move away from the PC market."